# Override the element mapped in the main.xsl file to NULL in import.xsl

Tags: xslt

we are trying to override the element mapped in the main.xsl file to NULL in import.xsl file using call template. But we are getting the target mapped twice instead of overriding. kindly help.

**main.xsl**

```
<db:LONG_DESCRIPTION xml:id="id_102">
<xsl:value-of select="corecomEBO:RevisedItem/corecomEBO:Description" xml:id="id_103"/>
</db:LONG_DESCRIPTION>

<xsl:call-template name="LONG_DESCRIPTION_Custom"/>
```

**import.xsl**

```
<xsl:template name="LONG_DESCRIPTION_Custom">
<db:LONG_DESCRIPTION      xmlns:db="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/APPS/INV_EBI_CHANGE_ORDER_PUB/PROCESS_CHANGE_ORDER_LIST/" xml:id="id_102" >
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</db:LONG_DESCRIPTION>
</xsl:template>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<db:LONG_DESCRIPTION xml:id="id_102">XXX</db:LONG_DESCRIPTION>
<db:LONG_DESCRIPTION xmlns:db="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/APPS/INV_EBI_CHANGE_ORDER_PUB/PROCESS_CHANGE_ORDER_LIST/" xml:id="id_102" />
```

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
<db:LONG_DESCRIPTION xmlns:db="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/APPS/INV_EBI_CHANGE_ORDER_PUB/PROCESS_CHANGE_ORDER_LIST/" xml:id="id_102" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Once an element has been instantiated by a transform there is no way to change it. As you have found, all another template can do is *add* to what has already been created.

If you are unable to modify `main.xsl` then the best you can do is apply a *second* transform that will alter the data produced by the first.

An alternative is to add a *priority* to an identical template in the imported transform that provides the wanted output. I can't help you with this unless I see the entirety of `main.xsl`.